# Firebase Auth method createUser not showing right parameters

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

In one of my View Controllers I have at the top `import FirebaseAuth` and I'm trying to use

```html
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { authResult, error in
  // ...
}
```

as in the docs, but when I type in `Auth.createUser` I only get `Auth.createUser(self: Auth)`. I didn't do anything like assign any delegates, it is a simple file.

[image]

When I type this

```html
Auth.createUser(withEmail: "", password: "" ) { (result, err) in

    if let err != nil {

        self.showError("Error creating user")
    } else {

    }

}
```

`Instance member 'createUser' cannot be used on type 'Auth'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?`. Why won't it recognize the Firebase Auth method with the right parameters (email, password)?

Comment: Clean Build Folder + Build didn't help as well

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: "", password: "" ) { (result, err) in
    if let err != nil {
        self.showError("Error creating user")
    } else {

    }
}
```

Doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start

I suggest reading about Singletone classes: https://medium.com/@nimjea/singleton-class-in-swift-17eef2d01d88 .

Comment: Forgive me, I posted the wrong code snippet at the beginning. I mean whenever I type `Auth.auth().createUser` it does not autocomplete to `createUser(withEmail: ""...)`, instead it shows the image I linked which is `Auth.auth.createUser(self: Auth)`.

In any case when I deleted my ViewController and re-added the same code..this time the intellisense picked up the version of `createUser` that we both are talking about.